# hibernate xml one-to-many JOIN three tables

Tags: xml, hibernate, one-to-many

i'm new to hibernate; inherited codebase that uses older version that uses .hbm.xml files( no annotations)

I have a table(say table A) which has one-to-many hibernate relationship to couple of tables( tables B and C), the "lazy" attribute is set as false; that gets me data from all three tables, when I'm doing hiberateTemplate.load(Table a). my situation is I need to do join against one of the child tables(table B) and look for a specific field value in Table B  and get records from all A,B,C only for that matching field value in Table B (Table B specific field).

Table A(Event)

```
    <set name="eventKeyIdentifiers" table="EventKeyIdentifier"
            inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="eventId" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="event.EventKeyIdentifiers" />
    </set>    

    <set name="eventStatuses" table="EventStatus"
            inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select" order-by="effectiveDate DESC">
        <key>
            <column name="eventId" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="event.EventStatuses" />
    </set>
```

Table B( Event Status)

```
    <many-to-one name="event" class="event.Event" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="eventId" length="36" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>

    <property name="statusCode" type="string">
        <column name="statusCode" length="100" not-null="true" />
    </property>
```

Table A (Event) needs to loaded for a specific "statusCode" (Table B)

Any suggestions?

Comment: How would you write a basic sql query to join three tables? You can write an HQL query similar to that. Look at the [HQL documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql) for help.

Answer (score 1):

DetchedCriteria helped!

```
        DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Event.class)
                                    .addOrder(Order.desc("eventProcessedDate"))
                                    .createAlias("eventStatuses", "evtStats")
                                    .add(Restrictions.naturalId()
                                        .set("evtStats.statusCode", status));
```